# AWX unable to cleanup jobs

Tags: postgresql, ansible, ansible-awx

I have a ver. 1.4.0 AWX operator running in EKS that I've migrated to an other cluster with the newer version of the operator (2.5.0) I've created an sql dump of the Postgres DB, and applied it to the new one. Everything works except one management job that is cleaning out the job history. On the old cluster this was pretty agressive due to large job outputs and I was deleting anything older than 7 days.
Now I've noticed that the new AWX deployment is failing to cleanup the job history that came from the other cluster. It only applies to playbook runs, as I can delete the inventory syncs and source updates using the awx-manage utility.
When I try to delete old jobs I get this error:

```
bash-5.1# awx-manage cleanup_jobs --days 10
Killed
```

Doesn't matter what I set after the `--days` flag. It always fails. The exit code is 137 but I was unable to find any info on this.
I tried running the command with `--traceback` and `-v 3` but was given no additional output.

Same happens when I try from the UI

```
DELETE api/v2/jobs/539243/ 500
A server error has occurred.
```

Is there a way to dig deeper into the `Killed` error or get rid of the corrupted entries directly from the DB?

Comment: did you have a look at awx-dispatcher.log ? maybe you'll find a bit more details about the awx-manage job that fails ? here's a link about types of logs and location : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/logfiles.html

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with jobs that had much larger job events (anything above 80,000) that caused the delete job to fail. In those cases I was stuck deleting the job events themselves. Once the history got below 80,000 job events I was able to delete the job manually. Here is what I ran in order to get the job events deleted (probably a more effective way to do this, but it did the job)

```
# Delete job events, 1000 at a time seemed to be the best way to run this without causing the container to either die out, or just start running the job event deletions really slow.
# This code deletes 1,000 at a time then loops through again. For some reason re-initializing the object again seemed to keep it from slowing down, so we use a nested loop for this.
# The example bellow will delete 100,000 job events. So if you need to remove more increase the number in "for j in range(0, 100)" to fit your use case

for j in range(0, 100):
    objs = JobEvent.objects.filter(job=<job_id>)
    for i in range(0,1000):
        objs[i].delete()
```

In order to see the number of job events a specific job had I would run the following

```
JobEvent.objects.filter(job=<job_id>).count()
```